# How to Sort a DIV OnClick Jquery by value of a custom attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-sortable

This code works perfect for sorting a dynamically created div:

```
<div id='1'>a</div>
<div id='2'>b</div>
<div id='3'>c</div>
<div id='4'>d</div>
<div id='5'>e</div>

<div id="addnew">Add New</div>



   $('#addnew').live('click',function() {

    newdiv = $("<div id='4'>AA</div>");

    div_id_after = Math.floor(parseFloat(newdiv.get(0).id));

    $('#'+div_id_after).after(newdiv);

});
```

All I want to do is take this same function and make it work to use a custom attribute "data-sort=" rather than ID.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use newdiv.attr('data-sort') to access custom attribute of your div

UPDATE:

Indeed if you later want to iterate over all div elements and use the 'data-sort' attribute for sorting, using jQuery you would do something like:

```
$("div.sortableDivClass").each(function(index, item) {
   var order = item.getAttribute('data-sort');
   // do the reshuffle based on the order
    ...


});
```

Comment: but that doesn't give access to each element in turn, does it? `newdiv.attr('data-sort')` when there's more than one ... would a callback be needed there? an `.each()`? If you dereferenced it with `.get(n)` you would have to rewrap it in a jQuery object before you could use `.attr()`

Comment: It may be a simplification on the sample, but you're creating the newdiv element by hand and just adding one div to it, attr() takes the attr of the first match, so why would you need to iterate over all the elements in the newdiv?

Comment: ~ Good point, I was thinking since it's called "data-sort" that it would be sorted on later on ... like when there's two "4" or something eventually.

Answer (score 2):

From your element, you can use `getAttribute()`.

```
var elem = newdiv.get(0);

var div_id_after = elem.getAttribute('data-sort');
```

---

Or with jQuery, you can use the `.data()` method.

```
var div_id_after = newdiv.data('sort');
```

This works because jQuery supports the HTML5 `data` attributes on older browsers too.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think .data uses HTML5 data attributes internally at all?

Comment: @Gary: You're probably right. I haven't looked but I'd imagine it is just getting the attribute.